# How to obtain two values from a sub-query to be used in the where clause of sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to use two values in the where clause to be tested for equality of two values obtained from a subquery. Since I am working on an existing application, I want to keep it as a subquery. The following is my query.

```
SELECT 
    o.EMAIL_ADDRESS, c.FIRST_NAME, p.PARTY_ID
FROM 
    ORDER o WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN  
    PARTY p WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.ORDER_ID = p.PARTY_ID 
INNER JOIN 
    CUSTOMER c WITH (NOLOCK) ON p.PARTY_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID 
WHERE 
    (o.EMAIL_ADDRESS, c.CUSTOMER_ID) IN (SELECT EMAIL_ADDRESS, CUSTOMER_ID 
                                         FROM CUSTOMER_MASTER 
                                         WHERE insert_date > '01/02/2019')
```

The problem I am facing is that the first value within the where clause, o.EMAIL_ADDRESS, throws the following error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

When I use a single value within the where clause it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

One method is with `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT o.EMAIL_ADDRESS, c.FIRST_NAME, p.PARTY_ID
FROM ORDER_HEADER oh  WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN  PARTY p WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.ORDER_ID = p.PARTY_ID 
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER c WITH (NOLOCK) ON p.PARTY_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID 
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM CUSTOMER_MASTER AS cm
    WHERE cm.insert_date > '01/02/2019'
    AND o.EMAIL_ADDRESS = cm.EMAIL_ADDRESS
    AND c.CUSTOMER_ID = cm.c.CUSTOMER_ID
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

`in` allows single column list only. So *create* single column.

```
SELECT o.EMAIL_ADDRESS, c.FIRST_NAME, p.PARTY_ID
FROM ORDER o  WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN  PARTY p WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.ORDER_ID = p.PARTY_ID 
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER c WITH (NOLOCK) ON p.PARTY_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID 
WHERE o.EMAIL_ADDRESS + cast(c.CUSTOMER_ID as varchar) 
IN (select EMAIL_ADDRESS + cast(CUSTOMER_ID as varchar)
from CUSTOMER_MASTER where insert_date > '01/02/2019')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS`.  I would also advise fixing the date format:

```
SELECT o.EMAIL_ADDRESS, c.FIRST_NAME, p.PARTY_ID
FROM ORDER o JOIN
     PARTY p 
     ON o.ORDER_ID = p.PARTY_ID JOIN
     CUSTOMER c 
     ON p.PARTY_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM CUSTOMER_MASTER cm
              WHERE cm.EMAIL_ADDRESS = o.EMAIL_ADDRESS AND
                    cm.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID AND
                    cm.insert_date > '2019-02-01'
             );
```

Your date constants should be in the YYYYMMDD format.

Based on your logic, though, I don't think you need all the `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT o.EMAIL_ADDRESS, c.FIRST_NAME, o.ORDER_ID
FROM ORDER o JOIN
     CUSTOMER c 
     ON o.ORDER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM CUSTOMER_MASTER cm
              WHERE cm.EMAIL_ADDRESS = o.EMAIL_ADDRESS AND
                    cm.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID AND
                    cm.insert_date > '2019-02-01'
             );
```

The table `PARTY` doesn't seem necessary, because the orders can align directly to the customers.